# Cocos2D. Endless background in all directions

Tags: background, cocos2d-iphone, scroll, textures, tile

I have one texture that i need to set as a background. Scrolling should be in left, right and bottom directions. I have tried to change texture coords, to swap row of 3 textures down and then swap horizontal textures... epic failure.
Does anyone know how to make a background from the same tiled texture in all directions?

Comment: Easily Googled: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WUwooABmg3Y

Comment: yes, but i need to add vertical tiling too

Comment: k look at CCParallaxNode here:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/3611/how-to-make-a-space-shooter-iphone-game

Answer (score 1):

You have many approaches to this, depending your needs:

If you are looking for a huge scrolling background (although not infinite) you could use  [CCBigImage extension](https://github.com/cocos2d/cocos2d-iphone-extensions/tree/master/Extensions/CCBigImage).

If you want infinite scrolling backgrounds, what @Skullz suggested is ok too. You can easily modify that code to support scrolling in both axis, instead of repositioning 2 images, you would reposition 4 of them.

Using that method, plus adding some random items to add some variation should be enough. You can also use CCParallaxNode for a better effect.

Comment: pabloruiz55 hej man, cool stuff. I have a similar problem trying to use ParallaxBackground with two sprite sheets and using CCSpriteFrameCache. I am working using retina display for iPhone and would like to give variety to the game by having not one image that keeps repeating itself but two images for each layer (e.g. one layer has clouds and the other has blue sky). Unfortunately the limitation of 2048x2048 does not allow to include bigger spritesheets and when I try to use 2 I get a frame rate drop. Shall I post a question with code?